# Sorting in DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have One DataTable Like This
I can not rearrange this data table as i want. My DataTable is

```
ID   DetailID  Name FirstName LastName Middle Year class Line 
4000  41001     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4000  41002     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4000  41003     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4000  41004     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4000  41005     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4000  41006     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4001  41007     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4001  41008     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4001  41009     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4001  41010     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4001  41011     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4002  41012     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4002  41013     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4002  41014     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4002  41015     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4002  41016     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
```

and i want to arrange this DataTable by Line Column. Like this

```
ID   DetailID  Name FirstName LastName Middle Year class Line 
4000  41001     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4001  41007     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4002  41012     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4000  41002     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4001  41008     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4002  41013     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4000  41003     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4001  41009     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4002  41014     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4000  41004     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4001  41010     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4002  41015     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4000  41005     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
4001  41011     x     y         z        z     y     z     2
4002  41016     x     y         z        z     y     z     3
4000  41006     x     y         z        z     y     z     1
```

so, how can i do this , please help me to arrange this datatable.

Comment: @AdarshShah I think he wants to sort them by `Line` column with first 1, first 2, first 3 then second 1, second 2, second 3 etc..

Comment: Yes I realized that...

Comment: 3 upvotes? Why? Just why?  Please post your attempt (and stop getting your mates to upvote you!)

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it works. You can probably try to make it simpler.

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SortOrder", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
var iCount = 0;
var previousLine = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    var Line = Convert.ToInt32(row["Line"]);

    if (previousLine != Line)
        iCount = 0;

    previousLine = Line;

    row["SortOrder"] = Line + iCount * 3;
    iCount++;
}

dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "SortOrder Asc";

dataTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Method 1:**

```
var newDataTable = yourtable.AsEnumerable()
                   .OrderBy(r=> r.Field<int>("ID"))
                   .ThenBy(r=> r.Field<int>("DetailID"))  
                   .CopyToDataTable();
```

**Method 2:**

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = "ID, DetailID ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "MyCol ASC";
```

Answer (score -1):

LINQ is your friend

```
var sortedTable = sourceTable.AsEnumberable().OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Line")).Select(r => r).CopyToDataTable();
```